# Is there any GIS extension for Apache Cassandra?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, gis

I want to use Cassandra for my web application, because it will manage a lot information. The problem is that it will also handle a lot of geographical data, so I need a GIS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) cassandra extension to capture, store, manipulate, analyze, manage, and present all types of geographical data. 

Something like PostGIS for PostgreSQL. Does it already exists? Something simillar? Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of our clients at PlayOrm(a client on top of cassandra with it's own command line client) is heavy into GIS so we are going to be adding features to store GIS data though I think they already exist.  I meet with someone next week regarding this so in the meantime, you may want to checkout PlayOrm.

Data will be read from cassandra and displayed on one fo the largest monitors I have seen with some big huge machine(s) backing it with tons of graphic's cards....pretty cool setup.

Currently, PlayOrm does joins and Scalable-SQL but it is very likely we will be adding spatial queries to the mix if we continue to do GIS data.